# is it possible use html tag or spannable in TextInputLayout hint?

Tags: android, html, hint, textinputlayout

I have a TextInputLayout in my layout and i want use html tag or spannable in it's hint but it does not work with it.

I search all links in google but the result was "it's not possible now and maybe in next version and updates be possible".

is it possible customize TextInputLayout view to accept html tag in hint? and how can i do this?

Comment: Adding some code would be a good idea.

Comment: @iMDroid Thanks for the help

Comment: @iMDroid you asked a question like mine last year. did you find any solution for it?

Comment: i meant post some code here to help the ppl understand your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add below code in layout xml file for TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/enter_message" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

In string.xml file add following code:

```
<string name="enter_message">Enter Message<font fgcolor="red">*</font></string>
```

Comment: You can't set HTML data using XML. It has to be done in code, otherwise the data doesn't take effect

Comment: @hamed can you add code for the same..it will be helpful to understand....